# Change Background Color with mouse Over reference by class JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have given class to a group of div's and want to change the background color of a div on mouse over it. What I did is this : 
**HTML**

```
<div class="menu_top">
<div id="1" class="menu_top_menu">Home</div> 
<div id="2" class="menu_top_menu">About Us</div> 
<div id="3" class="menu_top_menu">Register</div> 
<div id="4" class="menu_top_menu">Contact Us</div> 
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.menu_top_menu').mouseover(function(){
    $('this').attr('style','background-color:yellow;');
    });
});
```

This do work with ID reference but I want to work with class. What am I doing Wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `$(this)` instead of `$('this')` - no quotation marks around `this`.

Also, you wouldn't normally use `attr()` to set the `style`, you'd use the [`.css()` method](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to set the particular CSS property in question:

```
$(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
```

Note that if the intention is to change the background only while the mouse is over the element (i.e., to change it back on mouse out) you can easily do it with no JS at all by using the `:hover` pseudo-class in your CSS:

```
div.menu_top_menu:hover {
    background-color : yellow;
}
```